# Unity ad works in editor but not on iPhone

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a very simple Advertisment statement that I know works
and I'm calling that class in another statement.
They show up and work in editor but not iPhone or Android. Unity ad is on and test mode is off.

Comment: do you get any error or suspicious log in xcode log?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting error that ads not available (or something similar) because you as a user (not developer) are not qualified to receive an ad yet and it can happen with almost any user.

Its recommended to add your device in Test Devices under Unity Ads so that you can receive test ads.